# How to use PC name inside ifdef ifndef statments

Tags: c++, templates, debugging, macros

How can I use my PC name in the ifdef statement instead of using the ONLINE_JUDGE macro.

I use the following debugging code where debug.h has all the debugging functions and when the ONLINE_JUDGE is not defined then my debugging function calls maps to debug.h else it just maps to empty deb(...)

```
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
#include "debug.h"
#else
#define deb(...)
#endif
```

I want to use something like

```
#ifdef MYPC
#include "debug.h"
#else
#define deb(..)
#endif
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out :)

Comment: Just add  compilation flag MYPC to your local compiler settings (and use #ifdef, #else, #endif). Just be advised online judge/competitive sites are not a good place to learn C++.
(The code shown usually shows how to solve the problem, but the quality of the C++ code is usually very very low).

Comment: Don't be afraid to get a proper local development environment like Visual Studio (the IDE, not the editor Code), Xcode, or one of many others. These will allow you to build something bigger than toy snippets of code. They also give you full control over what is/isn't defined, and what values those defines assume.

Answer (score 2):

you can use -DMYPC flag in g++ building:

```
g++ -DMYPC -o test main.c
```

then

```
#IFDEF MYPC
#include "debug.h"
#else
#define deb(..)
#ENDIF
```